# How to write a accept condition for droppable td , so that it accept only its neighbor td in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have table in which only one td will be empty . Here user can drag and drop the td elements .I am trying to write condition so that empty td accept only its neighbor td elements.

Can you please suggest me the accept condition so that ui.droppable or empty td accept its neighbor td .

Code:

```
$("#dropdiv #c tr td").draggable({
    appendTo: "body",
    helper: 'clone',
    cursor: "move",
    revert: "invalid"
});

$('#c tr td').droppable({
    accept: function(event, ui) {
        return ($(this).html().trim().length == 0)
    },
    drop:function (event, ui ) {
        $(this).append(ui.draggable.text());
        $(ui.draggable).empty();
    }
});
```

From above code if the td is empty then only the td accept ui.draggable .

Please find the demo here:http://jsfiddle.net/ggbhat/6JKWp/2/

In demo the middle(5) td is empty , i want only 2,4,6,8 are accepted by 5 .

Comment: Are you sure that's the right Fiddle?  There's no TABLEs there that I see.

Comment: For some time, I was like, is he referring to divs as tds like the old style before divs were defined.

Comment: @ScottSauyet sorry for the mistake , now i have updated correct Fiddle link .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like,

```
        $('#c tr td').droppable({
           accept: function(ui, item) {
               if($(this).html().trim().length != 0)
                  return false;

               if($(ui).index()==$(this).index())
                 return true;

               var next=$(this).next().get(0);
               var prev=$(this).prev().get(0);
               var me=ui.get(0);

               if(me==next||me==prev)
               return true;

               return false;  
           },
          drop:function (event, ui ) {
                $(this).append(ui.draggable.text());
                $(ui.draggable).empty();   
          }
       });
```

Comment: @ggbhat: This really looks like it shouldn't work in general.  The code, as I read it, allows you to drop the one to the left, the one to the right, or any one in the same column.  That doesn't sound like the original description, which is that you wanted just immediate neighbors.

Comment: "In demo the middle(5) td is empty , i want only 2,4,6,8 are accepted by 5"- This requirement says it I guess.

Comment: @ScottSauyet: You are right , i wanted only the immediate neighbors . But Mathew solution allows you to drop the one to the left, the one to the right, or any one in the same column . I made small changes to Mathew answer it works for me as required .                              Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ggbhat/6JKWp/3/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to selectively accept or reject elements, assign your neighbouring `td` elements some class or id, then do something like this:

```
    $("#c tr td").droppable({
          accept: function(d) { 
              if(d.hasClass("neighbouring_table_element")){ 
                 return true;
              }
          }
   });
```